# Run SSH command automatically

Tags: node.js, npm, ssh, nuxt.js

Currently I'm using PuTTY to manually login and run SSH commands on my server.
Is it possible to login and trigger a SSH command by calling a PHP file, cron job or something like that?

What I would like to archive is to easily run NuxtJS `npm run generate` on my server without having to login manually first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could have a bash file and add it as a script in your `package.json`

*generate.sh*

```sh
# login to your server, and execute some commands
ssh root@my.server.com "cd /root/my-app && some-other-command"
```

*package.json*

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "generate": "bash ./generate.sh"
  }
}
```

In the end you could:

```
$ npm run generate
```

Which will login to your ssh server, and execute the commands in `generate.sh`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to call/run the .sh from PHP?